# Terminal command ls/cd not opening external usb drive

Tags: terminal, finder, hard-drive, usb, bash

I have a usb drive that I can access via Finder and rStudio but I cannot open the drive via Terminal to analyze its contents. I can see the usb drive name when I enter `cd /Volumes && ls` but when I attempt to change directory to drive i.e. `cd /Volumes/USBDrive` I keep getting error `cd: no such file or directory: /Volumes/USBDrive`

Output of `ls -l` is `drwxrwxrwx  1 Fayyy  staff  131072 Jan  1  1980 USBDrive`

Answer (score 1):

> Output of `ls -l` is `drwxrwxrwx  1 Fayyy  staff  131072 Jan  1  1980 USBDrive`

It looks like you might have a trailing *space* character in the *name* of the **USB** *drive*, try `cd '/Volumes/USBDrive '`, and it works you might want to remove the trailing *space* character in the *name*.

Comment: To whomever just downvoted this answer, care to give a valid reason for doing so?